# unions in c (memory storage pattern of unions )

Tags: c

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>

   union Data
   {
     float f;
     char  str;
   };

   main( )
  {
    union Data data;

    data.f = 11111;
    data.str='j';

    printf( "data.f : %f\n", data.f);
    printf( "data.str : %c\n", data.str);

    return 0;
  }
```

in this case i am able to access both the value at the same time 
output is 11111.0005,j

but if i reverse the assignments i.e   data.str='j';
                            and then    data.f = 11111;

then the value of str is not accessible   why?﻿

Comment: um… a `union` is not a `struct`… the members share the same memory. if you assign to one, that will – at least partially – overwrite the other one.

Comment: I get `data.f : 11111.103516`, which can be explained. Your value of `11111.0005` has no logical explanation, other than the code exhibits **undefined behavior**.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? This seems precisely what you would expect if the two values overlap in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `union` overlays a `float` type and a `char` type in the same memory. But the `char` type is only one byte as opposed to the `float` which needs 4 bytes.

Although a simple `char` type might - on 32-bit platforms - need as much memory reserved as a simple `float` type, in the `union` only one byte of the `char` field is written to.

So when you write to it, it corrupts only one byte of the `float` type. That is why you can still `printf()` the `char`, and why the `float` way of seeing it has been corrupted.

I have added another member to the `union`, a byte array, so we can see what is happening. Notice that writing `'j'` (hex value 0x6A) to `str` only affects the first byte of the `union`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

union Data
{
    float f;
    char str;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
};

int main(void)
{
    union Data data;
    int i;

    data.f = 11111;        // write to float
    // show the union as bytes
    printf("bytes:");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %02X", data.bytes[i]);
    printf("\n");

    data.str='j';          // write to char
    // show the union as bytes
    printf("bytes:");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %02X", data.bytes[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf( "data.f : %f\n", data.f);
    printf( "data.str : %c\n", data.str);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
bytes: 00 9C 2D 46
bytes: 6A 9C 2D 46
data.f : 11111.103516
data.str : j
```

If, as in your question, you reverse the assignments, is it now obvious why `str='j'` no longer exists? It is because the `float` requires *all* of the `union`.